# working with assets folder or drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-assets

I am creating an app using android studio.
i created the assets folder and created sub directories under it for each activity i am using (each one has a different set of images).
But on the other hand i want to support multiply screen resolutions which as i read is supported using drawable folder's, also drawable doesn't support sub directories.
I am using API 19 at the moment.

Putting all the images in drawable folder will be a bug mass.

How can i achieve my goal of order in my images and supporting multiple screen resolutions

Thank you in advance

Comment: Stay with the `drawable` folder.

Comment: but i wont be bale to "know" which images belong to which activity, i will have total mass.
unlike assets which i can load only the images under a specific folder for that activity

Comment: Maybe you can store them in a map. Activity,int pairs?

Answer (score 1):

there are subfoldes in drawable. take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Problem is that if i am loading activity1 and want to load the images that belong to this activity i am unable to do it since the drawable folder is loaded to the resources and reference with an Int unlike Assets which i can ask the activity to load all the images under "activity1" folder.

Answer (score 1):

The drawables folders allow you to save various resolution versions of an image into separate folders. The OS will choose the right asset based on the device screen density for you when you ask for @drawables/image_name. /assets is more like a normal file directory. In general if you pull from assets you need to handle resolution differences on your own.